# still "httpd dead but subsys locked" even following the fix of some source

Tags: redhat, httpd

Here is what I have tried so far:

edit: /etc/sysconfig/httpd

```
PIDFILE=/var/run/httpd.pid
```

edit: /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf

```
PidFile /var/run/httpd.pid
```

then

```
killall -9 httpd
```

result:

```
httpd: no process killed
```

then:

```
sudo rm -f /var/lock/subsys/httpd
sudo service httpd restart
```

result:

```
Stopping httpd:                                            [FAILED]
Starting httpd:                                            [  OK  ]
```

then:

```
sudo service httpd status
```

result:

```
httpd dead but subsys locked
```

Still no LUCK, did I miss a fix on this issue? please help

NOTE: its not generating a httpd.pid on /var/run when I start the httpd

Apache Error Log

```
[Tue Dec 10 06:27:42 2013] [notice] Digest: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Tue Dec 10 06:27:42 2013] [notice] Digest: done
[Tue Dec 10 06:31:27 2013] [notice] Digest: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Tue Dec 10 06:31:27 2013] [notice] Digest: done
[Tue Dec 10 06:45:21 2013] [notice] Digest: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Tue Dec 10 06:45:21 2013] [notice] Digest: done
[Tue Dec 10 06:52:47 2013] [notice] Digest: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Tue Dec 10 06:52:47 2013] [notice] Digest: done
[Tue Dec 10 06:55:46 2013] [notice] Digest: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Tue Dec 10 06:55:46 2013] [notice] Digest: done
[Tue Dec 10 07:06:21 2013] [notice] Digest: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Tue Dec 10 07:06:21 2013] [notice] Digest: done
[Tue Dec 10 07:13:35 2013] [notice] Digest: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Tue Dec 10 07:13:35 2013] [notice] Digest: done
[Tue Dec 10 07:20:44 2013] [notice] Digest: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Tue Dec 10 07:20:44 2013] [notice] Digest: done
```

ADDITIONAL INFO

ps auxwww

```
USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
root         1  0.0  0.2  19316  1512 ?        Ss   06:44   0:00 /sbin/init
root         2  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    06:44   0:00 [kthreadd]
root         3  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    06:44   0:00 [ksoftirqd/0]
root         4  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    06:44   0:00 [migration/0]
root         5  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    06:44   0:00 [watchdog/0]
root         6  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    06:44   0:00 [events/0]
root         7  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    06:44   0:00 [cpuset]
root         8  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    06:44   0:00 [khelper]
root        17  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    06:44   0:00 [netns]
root        18  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    06:44   0:00 [async/mgr]
root        23  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    06:44   0:00 [xenwatch]
root        24  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    06:44   0:00 [xenbus]
root        72  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    06:44   0:00 [sync_supers]
root        74  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    06:44   0:00 [bdi-default]
root        75  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    06:44   0:00 [kintegrityd/0]
root        77  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    06:44   0:00 [kblockd/0]
root        84  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    06:44   0:00 [kseriod]
root       193  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    06:44   0:00 [khungtaskd]
root       194  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    06:44   0:00 [kswapd0]
root       195  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        SN   06:44   0:00 [ksmd]
root       248  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    06:44   0:00 [aio/0]
root       251  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    06:44   0:00 [crypto/0]
root       263  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    06:44   0:00 [khvcd]
root       343  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    06:44   0:00 [kstriped]
root       533  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    06:44   0:00 [jbd2/xvda1-8]
root       534  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    06:44   0:00 [ext4-dio-unwrit]
root       557  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    06:44   0:00 [flush-202:1]
root       564  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    06:44   0:00 [khubd]
root       614  0.0  0.1  10772   716 ?        S<s  06:44   0:00 /sbin/udevd -d
root       834  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    06:45   0:00 [kauditd]
root       985  0.0  0.0   9220   588 ?        Ss   06:45   0:00 /sbin/dhclient -1 -q -lf /var/lib/dhclient/dhclient-eth0.leases -pf /var/run/dhclient-eth0.pid eth0
root      1022  0.0  0.2 248984  1272 ?        Sl   06:45   0:00 /sbin/rsyslogd -c 4
root      1072  0.0  0.1  64396  1096 ?        Ss   06:45   0:00 /usr/sbin/sshd
ntp       1079  0.0  0.2  30424  1656 ?        Ss   06:45   0:00 ntpd -u ntp:ntp -p /var/run/ntpd.pid -g
root      1094  0.0  0.3  86952  2356 ?        Ss   06:45   0:00 sendmail: accepting connections
smmsp     1102  0.0  0.3  78428  2068 ?        Ss   06:45   0:00 sendmail: Queue runner@01:00:00 for /var/spool/clientmqueue
mongod    1115  0.4  2.2 627080 13872 ?        Sl   06:45   0:35 /usr/bin/mongod -f /etc/mongod.conf
root      1123  0.0  0.2 117288  1228 ?        Ss   06:45   0:00 crond
root      1134  0.0  0.0  23724   396 ?        Ss   06:45   0:00 /usr/sbin/atd
zend      1191  0.0  0.1  23956  1084 ?        Ss   06:45   0:00 /usr/local/zend/bin/watchdog -c /usr/local/zend/etc/watchdog-monitor.ini -u 221 -g 498 -s monitor
zend      1193  0.0  0.5 350012  3616 ?        Ssl  06:45   0:00 /usr/local/zend/bin/MonitorNode /usr/local/zend/etc/monitor_node.ini /usr/local/zend/etc/conf.d -e
zend      1266  0.0  0.1  23956  1092 ?        Ss   06:45   0:00 /usr/local/zend/bin/watchdog -c /usr/local/zend/etc/watchdog-sc.ini -u 221 -g 498 -s scd
zend      1268  0.0  0.5 656968  3316 ?        Ssl  06:45   0:00 /usr/local/zend/bin/scd -p /usr/local/zend/etc/scd.ini -e
zend      1325  0.0  0.1  23956  1088 ?        Ss   06:45   0:00 /usr/local/zend/bin/watchdog -c /usr/local/zend/etc/watchdog-deployment.ini -u 221 -g 498 -s zdd
zend      1327  0.1  0.6 203324  3748 ?        Ssl  06:45   0:09 /usr/local/zend/bin/zdd /usr/local/zend/etc/zdd.ini -e
zend      1374  0.0  0.1  23956  1088 ?        Ss   06:45   0:00 /usr/local/zend/bin/watchdog -c /usr/local/zend/etc/watchdog-jq.ini -u 221 -g 498 -s jqd
zend      1376  0.0  0.6 137456  4140 ?        Ss   06:45   0:01 /usr/local/zend/bin/jqd -f /usr/local/zend/etc/jqd.ini -e
root      1420  0.0  0.1  23956  1088 ?        Ss   06:45   0:00 /usr/local/zend/bin/watchdog -c /usr/local/zend/etc/watchdog-lighttpd.ini -u zend -g zend -s lighttpd
zend      1422  0.0  0.3  26840  1880 ?        Ss   06:45   0:00 /usr/local/zend/gui/lighttpd/sbin/lighttpd -m /usr/local/zend/gui/lighttpd/lib -f /usr/local/zend/gui/lighttpd/etc/lighttpd.conf -D
root      1446  0.0  0.0   4164   576 tty1     Ss+  06:45   0:00 /sbin/mingetty /dev/tty1
root      1448  0.0  0.0   4164   576 tty2     Ss+  06:45   0:00 /sbin/mingetty /dev/tty2
root      1450  0.0  0.0   4164   576 tty3     Ss+  06:45   0:00 /sbin/mingetty /dev/tty3
root      1452  0.0  0.0   4164   576 tty4     Ss+  06:45   0:00 /sbin/mingetty /dev/tty4
root      1455  0.0  0.0   4164   572 tty5     Ss+  06:45   0:00 /sbin/mingetty /dev/tty5
root      1459  0.0  0.1  10768   688 ?        S<   06:45   0:00 /sbin/udevd -d
root      1460  0.0  0.1  10768   688 ?        S<   06:45   0:00 /sbin/udevd -d
root      1461  0.0  0.1   4176   624 hvc0     Ss+  06:45   0:00 /sbin/agetty /dev/hvc0 38400 vt100-nav
root      1462  0.0  0.0   4164   572 tty6     Ss+  06:45   0:00 /sbin/mingetty /dev/tty6
root      1472  0.0  2.2 337484 13888 ?        SN   06:45   0:00 /usr/bin/python -tt /usr/sbin/yum-updatesd
root      1474  0.0  0.1   9336  1204 ?        SN   06:45   0:00 /usr/libexec/gam_server
root      1483  0.0  0.6 100236  3908 ?        Ss   06:47   0:00 sshd: ec2-user [priv]
ec2-user  1486  0.0  0.2 100236  1744 ?        S    06:47   0:00 sshd: ec2-user@pts/0
ec2-user  1487  0.0  0.4 109456  3012 pts/0    Ss   06:47   0:00 -bash
ec2-user  1963  0.0  0.1 108112  1132 pts/0    R+   08:58   0:00 ps auxwww
```

sudo find /etc/httpd /etc/zce.rc -type f -exec grep -i errorlog {} /dev/null \;

```
/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf:# ErrorLog: The location of the error log file.
/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf:# If you do not specify an ErrorLog directive within a <VirtualHost>
/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf:ErrorLog logs/error_log
/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf:#    ErrorLog logs/dummy-host.example.com-error_log
/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf.rpmnew:# ErrorLog: The location of the error log file.
/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf.rpmnew:# If you do not specify an ErrorLog directive within a <VirtualHost>
/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf.rpmnew:ErrorLog logs/error_log
/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf.rpmnew:#    ErrorLog logs/dummy-host.example.com-error_log
/etc/httpd/conf.d/zendserver_gui.conf:        ErrorLog /usr/local/zend/var/log/gui_vhost_error.log
/etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf:ErrorLog logs/ssl_error_log
```

Comment: Check Apache's error log.

Comment: run: sudo nano /var/log/httpd/error_log and this is what I got [Tue Dec 10 06:45:21 2013] [notice] Digest: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Tue Dec 10 06:45:21 2013] [notice] Digest: done

Comment: Could you add the output of `sudo netstat -apn|grep -w 80`?

Comment: run: sudo netstat -apn|grep -w 80 --- nothing happen or no display

Comment: Mmm.  That's not it, then.  Although I confess I'm flailing about slightly, trying to get a handle on this, could you try `sudo apachectl configtest`?  And perhaps `cat /selinux/enforce`?

Comment: post the output out ps auxwww ?

Comment: @MadHatter run: sudo apachectl configtest.. it produces: /etc/sysconfig/httpd: line 32: ./etc/zce.rc: No such file or directory
Syntax OK

Comment: @EricDANNIELOU - updated my question

Comment: What is this lighthttpd? Does it try to run on the same port as apache?

Comment: that is used for running zend server, it is configured to use port: 10081 for http and 10082 for https

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Had the same error on my server:

```
> service httpd status
httpd dead but subsys locked
```

Found, that the directory /var/run/httpd was NOT readable/executable by world:

```
drwx------   2 root      apache    4096 Apr 23 14:15 /var/run/httpd
```

Therefore any user (beside root) could not examine the pidfile (which did exist)!
The httpd-Process was already running fine, but the service command could not read the pidfile ...

```
# chmod a+rx /var/run/httpd
```

did fix the issue:

```
> service httpd status
httpd (pid  2848) is running...
```

Comment: Tried **sudo -i** and it worked.

Answer (score 3):

Recently updated to RHEL 6 and had the same problem.  After a lot of back and forth, I discovered that the default value for the location of the PID file in the `/etc/sysconfig/httpd` file and the `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf` file were different.  The default was `/var/run/httpd/httpd.pid` and the value in the httpd.conf file was `/var/run/httpd.pid`.

I fixed the value in the `httpd.conf` file, created the httpd directory under `/var/run`, and the bogus message is gone.

Comment: This saved me a day

Answer (score 0):

At the moment, the single most pressing issue is that you've got a fatal error in your config file.  The output from `apachectl configtest` is pretty definitive.

What you do about it is less clear.  As others have noted, the inclusion of `/etc/zce.rc` is a hangover from Zend, about which I know very little.  If you think you need that, you need to find out where the specified file has gone, and get it back; your system backups will be of help here.  If you don't think you need it, you could try commenting line 32 out of `/etc/sysconfig/httpd` and see if apache will start up then.

**Edit**: just to make really sure we're not missing some important error output because it's going elsewhere, could you edit into your question the output of

```
find /etc/httpd /etc/zce.rc -type f -exec grep -i errorlog {} /dev/null \;
```

**Edit 2**: ah, they're relative paths.  Could you also add the value of `ServerRoot`?

Comment: changed ./etc/zce.rc to /etc/zce.rc then run again sudo apachectl configtest, it produces "Syntax OK".... I also tried commenting it, also Syntax OK but both didnt work.. the httpd is still not up

Comment: Did you try the `cat /selinux/enforce` I asked for above?

Comment: sorry missed that: here is the result: cat: /selinux/enforce: No such file or directory

Comment: OK, that's not it, either.

Comment: updated my question for the details you asked..

Comment: I dont understand you correctly, sorry, this is the ServerRoot right? /etc/httpd -- on the definition it says where you can find the conf and logs? please correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: Nope, that's what I wanted.  Can you confirm that the contents of `/etc/httpd/logs/error_log` and `/etc/httpd/logs/ssl_error_log` are as you've shown above?  If that doesn't catch anything, I'm about out of ideas.

Comment: yep thats confirmed, I checked again.. I guess I will just select a different linux platform and see if I can copy the content :-( , thanks for the effort MadHatter

Answer (score 0):

Had to change httpd.config in /etc/httpd/conf/

from:
PidFile run/httpd.pid
to:
PidFile /var/run/httpd.pid

Also, changed httpd file in /etc/sysconfig/

from:

## PIDFILE=/var/run/httpd/httpd.pid

to:
PIDFILE=/var/run/httpd.pid

Run the following comand:

killall -9 httpd

then, to remove httpd lock:

rm -f /var/lock/subsys/httpd

And restarted Apache:
service httpd restart

Answer (score -1):

I ended up switching Linux Platform from RedHat to CentOs and started again from scratch and everything was working smoothly.

- not sure if this is a platform issue but it ended fixing my problem.